# hyperref colorlinks invalid in OverLeaf template

Tags: hyperref

I am preparing a manuscript​ for journal Geophysical Research Letters​ using Overleaf.

The [template link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/agu-geophysical-research-letters-agutex-article/rnyzczmyvkbj#.WZWvbneGMUF) is here, Replace the content in file agujournaltemplate.tex as below:

```
\documentclass[draft]{agujournal2019}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
\section{section one}

use \cite{Boug10}

\bibliography{agusample}
\end{document}
```

The journal ​require cross-references in blue marks (here the reference), but templates in OverLeaf do not have this function. I tried to add some codes to file agujournal2019.cls, but it didn't work anywhere.

```
\usepackage[colorlinks = true]{hyperref}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running `\documentclass` with the option `draft`, you're disabling some (actually, most) of the work of the `hyperref` package. In particular, the option prevents the citation call-out from being rendered in a color other than black.

What to do? I would like to suggest that you load `hyperref` *before* executing `\documentclass`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % load 'hyperref' first
\documentclass[draft]{agujournal2019}
\journalname{Whatever}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lineno,soul}

\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\noindent
use \cite{Boug10}

\bibliography{agusample}
\end{document}
```